# Is it possible to make GitHub render a Markdown within a folder, with a name different than Readme?

Tags: git, github, markdown

I've push some text templates I use, since I usually use my git to show my work, and due to my profession we use a lot of documents, I wanted to share some template in Markdown format.

I understand github automatically render Markdown file with README Name, but is it possible to make github to render a markdown file with a different name.

I've done some search and came out with no result, In advance I apologize if this has being asked to many times.

Thank you

Comment: IIRC, github renders all files ending with `.md` as markdown.

Comment: Yes, but this one has to be clicked in order for it to render it, and not when you enter a folder like it does with readme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your name any file `Foo.md`, you can go to that file in the repository browse view and it'll render the markdown file.

For example, here's a markdown file from my personal blog: https://github.com/awreece/codearcana/blob/master/content/performance/achieving_maximum_memory_bandwidth.md

Comment: Thanks for you answer Alex, I wondered if there was a way for it render it, when you click on the folder and not on the file.

Comment: No, github only renders files named like README for the folder.